# Handle redirects with OAuth 2.0?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, oauth

What is a good way to handle redirects in React Native with OAuth? There are external APIs I need to call, so I’ve registered my app, but I’m unclear what the redirect URI should be. For a web app, it would make sense how to handle this, but I’m not sure with React Native.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do in React Native is setup your application for deep linking.  A deep link is a way for another application or in this case your browser/WebView to say "Hey!  I'd like to pass this information back to a native app".

Setup:

1. Setup a url scheme in Xcode.  This will allow you to redirect to url's formatted something like this myApp://oauthLogin
2. Setup [Linking](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html)

From there you should be able to create an event listener for the Redirect URI that you pass to the oauth service, in this case your deep link.

```js
componentDidMount() {
  Linking.addEventListener('url', (url) => {
    console.log(url);
    // => myApp://oauthLogin?authCode=abc123
  });
}
```

You will have to add extra code the make sure the url is in the correct format but i hope that gets you closer!

Comment: Thanks! I've seen this method around, but some of the posts mentioning it are kind of outdated, so I wasn't sure if there was a different way. I have a test app now that is using deep linking, so I'll continue to roll with this method.

Comment: Toby, would you mind adding some context to this? I am pulling my hair out trying to get this to work. I am using the Lyft API and trying to redirect back to my app once a user accepts the permissions from the Lyft website in Safari. My question is here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47610827/redirecting-back-to-app-after-user-accepts-permissions-oauth2

Comment: The downside to this is that when redirected back to your URL scheme after authentication, the user will be presented with a "Open this link in myApp?" style dialog. I have however seen apps do this without this issue, i.e the browser just closes and redirects back to app immediately after authentication. Any ideas?